# ios - resize the image in a particular shape of the frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

I am trying to resize the image in the particular shape of the image frame, Here i want to show the image to the exact frame inside the glass.Could anyone here give an idea of how we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement. to add tattoos on body.
I used [this class](https://github.com/joshrl/FreeTransform) for this

This might use to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i checked the class it's has four edges using that we can resize the control. But here my requirement is i should place the images inside the transparent png image which is placed in the images view.

Comment: Yes,You need to modified that class.
And you can place your image over bg image and you can resize accordingly. Than you have to create new image from screen rendering.